# get files from directory in bash and build JSON object using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq, ls

I am trying to build list of JSON objects with the files in a particular directory. I am looping thru the `files` and creating the expected output object as string. I am sure there is a better way of doing this using `jq`.

Can someone please help me out here?

```
# input
files=($( ls * )) 
prefix="myawesomeprefix"
# expected output

{
  "listoffiles": [
    {"file":"myawesomeprefix/file1.txt"},
    {"file":"myawesomeprefix/file2.txt"},
    {"file":"myawesomeprefix/file3.txt"},
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have any "problematic" file names, e.g. ones that have new lines as part of their name, the following should work:

```
ls -1 | jq -Rn '{ listoffiles: [inputs | { file: "prefix/\(.)" }] }'
```

It reads each line as string, and reads them through the `inputs` filter (must be combined with `-n` null-input). It then builds your object.

```
$ cat <<LS | jq -Rn '{ listoffiles: [inputs | {file:"prefix/\(.)"}] }'
file1
file2
file with spaces
LS
{
  "listoffiles": [
    {
      "file": "prefix/file1"
    },
    {
      "file": "prefix/file2"
    },
    {
      "file": "prefix/file with spaces"
    }
  ]
}
```

You *could* use `for` with a glob which should handle new lines in file names as well. But it requires you to chain 2 jq commands:

```
for f in *; do
  printf '%s' "$f" | jq -Rs '{file:"prefix/\(.)"}';
done | jq -s '{listoffiles:.}'
```

To specify the prefix as variable from the outside, use `--arg`, e.g.

```
jq --arg prefix "yourprefixvalue" '$prefix + .'
```

Comment: how do I replace `prefix` with the value defined in a variable outside like `prefix="myawesomeprefix"`?

Comment: --var is not a valid option. I am using jq 1.5. I tried `ls -1 | jq -Rn --arg $prefix "yourprefixvalue" '{ listoffiles: [inputs | { file: "${prefix}/\(.)" }] }'` but that returns null.

Comment: also tried `ls -1 | jq -Rn --arg prefix "yourprefixvalue" '{ listoffiles: [inputs | { file: "${prefix}/\(.)" }] }'` but that prints $prefix as literal.

Comment: You would also use the `"\( EXPR )"` syntax for jq variables, e.g. `"\($prefix)/\(.)"`.  Or you just use `+` for string concatenation.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. --var should have been `--arg`. When used inside a string, variables have to be interpolated too, or used outside of a string literal.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the nice little command line tool `jc`:

```
ls | jc --ls
```

It converts the output of many shell commands to JSON. For reference have a look there in Github https://github.com/kellyjonbrazil/jc .

Then you can transform the result using `jq`:

```
ls | jc --ls | jq "{ listoffiles: [.[] | { file: (\"$prefix/\" + .filename) }] }"
```

Answer (score 2):

You [shouldn't](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) parse the output of `ls`. If installed, you could use `tree` with the `-J` option to produce a JSON listing, which you can transform to your needs using `jq`:

```bash
tree -aJL 1 | jq '
  {listoffiles: first.contents | map({file: ("myawesomeprefix/" + .name)})}
'
```

Or more comfortably using `--arg`:

```bash
tree -aJL 1 | jq --arg prefix myawesomeprefix '
  {listoffiles: first.contents | map({file: "\($prefix)/\(.name)"})}
'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is another alternative :

```
jq -n --arg prefix "myawesomeprefix"\
    '.listoffiles = ($ARGS.positional |
                     map({file:($prefix+"/"+.)}))'\
    --args *
```

Comment: Is there an advantage of writing `.property = (filters)` over `{property: filters}`?

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using jq 1.5 so args is not a valid option. that's the error I am getting.

Comment: @knittl Your are right, `{property: filters}` is better in this context.